# Are there ways/methods to figure out how to connect to a printer?

Tags: printing, printer

There is a printer in the office, and a window 7 laptop can use it for printing. But we don't know to connect to the printer from another laptop with ubuntu. We don't know how the printer setting was done on the windows 7 laptop, whether it is a networked printer or any other kinds of connection, we don't know.

the printer is HP Laser Jet Pro MFP M125nw

Are there ways/methods to figure out how to connect to that printer from the ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of cable is used to connect the printer to the Win7 laptop? If there is no cable on the printer (except the power cord), then it uses a WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings from the physical control panel of the printer. From there you can discover whether it's networked, and if yes, its IP and network address. Then, assuming the Ubuntu laptop is on the same LAN, you should be able to discover it from Ubuntu by going to Settings -> Printer.

If the printer is not networked, you should connect it to the laptop via USB cable and it should install the required drivers automatically. If not, you'll have to install the drivers by hand; the best way to do so is to find them on the manufacturer's website.

Unfortunately there's not much more that can be said without knowing more details (manufacturer, model...) about the printer.